Should I wait to hear from the Issuer of a PCN
I recently rented a car in the United Kingdom.  A couple of weeks later, Enterprise contacted me by email to say that they have received notice of an alleged violation and are charging me a £35 admin fee.  In this email, they have included the PCN reference and the issuing council.  They say that they have passed my details as the driver on to the council.
My question is do I need to act on this now, or do I wait to hear directly from the council.  My concern is that half the penalty is waived if I pay within 14 days.
Should I wait until hearing directly from the council, or should I pay now?

It depends. If you think you did an error: pay now. Else dispute. But it is possible that anyway you must pay the rental company a fee (and good luck on receiving a refund from council). So it depends on how much you must pay and how sure you are that it is their error" both thing we cannot asses in your question.

It doesn't directly answer your question, but you might find this helpful: https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/reclaim/parking-ticket-appeals/

I suggest you wait until you've been issued an actual PCN – you've only been told about a reference number of a notice issued to the rental company. I believe the 50% discount period is from the date you were issued the notice, not the date of the violation. If the notice is issued by post, some authorities extend the 14-day grace period to 21 days.

. . . have they asked you to pay their parking charge, or only an admin fee? You should pay or dispute a PCN issued in your name. That is why they passed your details to the council.

@WeatherVane Enterprise has just charged me an admin fee, it's my understanding that I'm responsible for the penalty.

You haven't been issued with a penalty notice, yet. Perhaps it will arrive in the post, which isn't very quick at this time of year. Or you could ask the rental agency what to do: reply to their email.

Are you a UK resident? If so, @Giacomo Catenazzi's comment is most relevant: accept or contest; entirely up to you based on the circumstances. Either way, the admin fee to Enterprise is gone.
If you are not a UK resident, accept that Enterprise have charged you a fee - whether justified or not - and then entirely ignore the PCN: it will go no further. If the penalty is justifiable, you will have paid a fee to the rental company and, morally IMHO, may consider that you have paid the fine. If it was not justifiable, the admin fee still justifies the questionably-justifiable administration 'work' by Enterprise.

It's also occurred to me that, if you are not a UK resident and never receive the PCN, the council may also come to the same conclusion: it's not worth the hassle of issuing a PCN to a foreigner which will almost certainly never be paid.
